# Sort an array of objects

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6

Is this the correct way to sort an array of objects?:

```
class Alarm{
    constructor(data){
        this.a = data.a;
        this.b = data.b;
    }
}

const a1 = new Alarm({a:4,b:1});
const a2 = new Alarm({a:1,b:4});
const a3 = new Alarm({a:2,b:3});
const a4 = new Alarm({a:3,b:2});

let a = [a1,a2,a3,a4];

a.sort((x,y)=>x.a>y.a);

for(const i of a){
    console.log(i)
}

a.sort((x,y)=>x.b>y.b);

for(const i of a){
    console.log(i)
}
```

When I look at the documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

They are doing this instead, which seems extremely awkward:

```
a.sort((x,y)=>
    {
        if(x.a>y.a) return 1;
        if(x.a<y.a) return -1;
        return 0;
    });
```

Comment: you will want `x.a - y.a`

Comment: `sort` should return 3 values. `1` for greater than, `0` for no change and `-1` for less than.

Comment: @Keith for string values, I'm not sure how `-` would work. For numeric values, it will work, but as OP is asking for better approach, I guess we should consider both situations

Comment: @Rajesh Same as `<` or `>`, it would be coerced to a number

Comment: It's not awkward. It's how the comparator function works. By the way, what is your question?

Comment: For strings I would use localeCompare.  And the numbers the `-`

Comment: @CodingIntrigue No. Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/ecovaz7s/). This case needs `1`, `-1`, 0

Comment: @torazaburo In python you return a bool not 1, -1, 0. Why didn't they design sort so the lambda could return a bool in JS?

Comment: @Rajesh I'm not sure I see what that JSFiddle is trying to prove, but I see that `>` is lexicographical comparison, instead of a mathematical equation.

Comment: *"In python you return a bool not 1, -1, 0."* Uhm, no: *"cmp specifies a custom comparison function of two arguments (iterable elements) which should **return a negative, zero or positive number** depending on whether the first argument is considered smaller than, equal to, or larger than the second argument"* https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted

Comment: I doubt there is any sort function that correctly works with a boolean as return value from the comparison callback, because a boolean can only represent two states, but the result of a comparison is one of three states: equal, smaller or larger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the difference for sorting

```
a.sort((x, y) => x.a - y.a);
```

Taken from [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> If `compareFunction` is supplied, the array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function. If a and b are two elements being compared, then:
>
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b, i.e. a comes first.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.
> - `compareFunction(a, b)` must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.

```js
class Alarm{
    constructor(data){
        this.a = data.a;
        this.b = data.b;
    }
}

const a1 = new Alarm({a:4,b:1});
const a2 = new Alarm({a:1,b:4});
const a3 = new Alarm({a:2,b:3});
const a4 = new Alarm({a:3,b:2});

let a = [a1, a2, a3, a4];

a.sort((x,y) => x.a - y.a);

console.log(JSON.stringify(a, 0, 4));
```

Comment: Is there a logical reason as to why the sort lambda should return 1, -1, and 0 instead of a boolean value. Seams really weird to me. Is there an alternative way of sorting where you can return booleans? I'm new to JS and ES6 :)

Comment: @Baz Because that's how it works. What would a boolean mean? The return value needs to indicate whether the first parameter comes before or after the second, or at the same location.

Comment: The sort needs to know if a value is equal, greater than, or less than.  A boolean does not give you that.

Comment: To understand why <=> are needed, a good idea is to look at how sort functions are done.  Look for bubble sort / quick sort etc.  Wiki most likely will have good docs on this.

Comment: great! the spaceship operator :)